# Tortoise SVN: Files already deleted from SVN repository showing as missing in local folder in windows machine

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

Some of the files along with the folder have been deleted from the SVN repository by another user. I took an update in my local and when doing "Check for modifications" the deleted files are listed as the "missing files". Could you please let me know how to remove the delete files appearing as missing ones from "Check for Modifications" list?

Answer (score 0):

In "Check for Modifications" --> Right click in the missing resource which you are sure is deleted from SVN repository (Mostly the parent folder will have "added(+)" as the status) --> Click "Undo Add" --> Select "Revert".

OR

In "Check for Modifications" --> Right click in the missing resource which you are sure is deleted from SVN repository --> Click "Revert" --> Choose "Revert all local modifications".